# How do I find filenames of files in my iPhones Documents folder?

Tags: iphone, ios, file

How do I get the last part of the filename in the Documents folder on the iPhone SDK.

/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/apptext/Documents/File.txt

I want the part that says File.txt, and ignore the rest of the path, how would I do that using the iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *path = "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/apptext/Documents/File.txt"

NSString *name = [path lastPathComponent];
```